# Why define a friend function inside class definition

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++, we are allowed to define a friend function inside the class definition
like:-

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a): mem(a){}
    ~A() {}
    friend void fun() {}
private:
    int mem;
};
void fun();
```

and then we can call this function, just like any regular function.

```
fun();
```

Can someone explain about (with examples):

1. In what cases do we need to define friend function inside the class
   definition.
2. What is special about this kind of definition which can not be
   achieved with just declaring function as friend in class and then
   defining the function outside.

Comment: Look for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52068027/1906174) to a related question. The main consideration are implicit conversions to `fun` parameters and ADL. Also! `void fun()` isn't really equivalent to in-class definition -- `inline void fun()` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already know what is a `friend` function, there is absolutely no special meaning to your example: what you have is a regular `friend` function, with its *declaration* and *definition* combined.

Recall that friendship needs to be *declared* inside the class that "friends" a function. After that, the function can be *defined* at some place, for which you have two choices:

- **Outside the class** - that is the common way of defining a friend function, or
- **Inside the class** - that is what your example has.

Basic considerations for going with one approach vs. the other are the same as the rules that you use to decide between *defining* a member-function inside or outside the class.